# Unable to send eth from an account to other

Tags: ethers.js

I'm trying to send Eth from one account to other. I'm unable to achieve this. This is doable in V5 but not in V6 of ether.js.
Upon printing tx, i have the hash of the tx, however there is no track of it in local node.
Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
  const [owner, userOne, userTwo, userFour] = await ethers.getSigners();
        console.log(await provider.getBalance(userFour))
  const tx = await userFour.sendTransaction({to:userOne.getAddress(), value:ethers.parseEther('1')})
        console.log(userOne.getAddress())
        console.log(tx)
        console.log(await provider.getBalance(userFour))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const [owner, userOne, userTwo, userFour] = await ethers.getSigners();
    console.log(await provider.getBalance(userFour.address));

    const userOneAddress = await userOne.getAddress();
    const tx = await userFour.sendTransaction({ to: userOneAddress, value: ethers.utils.parseEther('1') });

    console.log(userOneAddress);
    console.log(tx);
    
    // Wait for the transaction to be mined
    await tx.wait();

    console.log(await provider.getBalance(userFour.address));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred while sending ETH:", error);
  }
})();
```

And if had problem check all console logs to detect the issue, If a certain part of the log is not correct, send it to me again.